# btrfs sub volume "Could not chdir to home directory /home/movie: No such file or directory"

Tags: partitioning, mount, filesystem, home-directory, btrfs

I get "Could not chdir to home directory /home/movie: No such file or directory" when trying to login. It looks like something with btrfs subvolume not mounting right.

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
/etc/fstab: static file system information.

 Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
 device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
 that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).

 <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
 / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=31831735-1e15-4eba-bf0f-414e8d0b674e /               btrfs   noauto,compress=lzo,noatime,autodefrag,subvol=@ 0       1
/home was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=31831735-1e15-4eba-bf0f-414e8d0b674e /home           btrfs   noauto,compress=lzo,noatime,autodefrag,subvol=@home 0       2
swap was on /dev/sdc1 during installation
UUID=0a4380c7-f088-44ad-8a9d-dba916afab85 none            swap    sw              0       0

movie@movie:/$ cd /home
movie@movie:/home$ ls
@  @home
movie@movie:/home$ cd @home
movie@movie:/home/@home$ ls
movie
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

noauto was the problem after it was removed it worked fine.